# Redirect a cat command when using wildcards as input

Tags: macos, command-line, sed, terminal.app

I have the following command that takes a certain part of a file in the current directory, writes it to a temporary file, gets a part of another file one directory up, writes it to a temporary file and then finally concatenates these two temporary files into one and outputs it to `result`:

```
sed -e '3003,$d' file1 > temp1;sed -n '3,$p' ../otherfile1 > temp2; cat temp1 temp2 > ../result1
```

This works for one file, but now I want to do this to a whole directory.

I thought that using a wildcard in the sed command would work:

```
sed -e '3003,$d' file* > temp1;sed -n '3,$p' ../otherfile* > temp2; cat temp1 temp2 > ../result*
```

but then of course it doesn't automagically know how to number the temporary files and the output file.

How can I use this command on a whole directory, outputting a unique result file for every concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as a loop in a bash shell rather than pass the entire list to sed.

```
let "n = 1"
for file in *
do
  sed -e '3003,$d' $file > temp1;sed -n '3,$p' ../$file > temp2; cat temp1 temp2 > ../result${n} ;
  let "n = n + 1"
done
```

Comment: How do I change the result filename for every iteration? My goal is to get `result1`, `result2, `result3`, etc. With the current loop it overwrites the `result1` file.

Answer (score 1):

Using a subshell, one can even avoid the "temp1" and "temp2" files. Also, if the filenames contain spaces, I tend to use "while":

```
n=1
ls | while read f; do
  ( sed -e '3003,$d' $f && sed -n '3,$p' ../$f ) > ../result${n}
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

Comment: Neat. Didn't think of that but a good solution to his problem. I also noticed the shell expansion math - I always like to be explicit though :)

Comment: You mean the "((...))" thinghy? I did that to avoid the bashism of "let", as it's not portable.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I'm such an idiot with math I prefer to spell it out :)